# See instance journalctl logs in docker container

Tags: docker, systemd, systemd-journald

I want to be able run docker container and see all instance journalctl logs.
In other words I want to see the same output of journalctl logs in Instance and in Docker container.

I was trying to mount the journald socket but still I don't see the journal logs from the instance

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

If `journalctl -u <service>.service` and not giving you the journal logs you want from your container, you can run `machinectl -l` to find the container's UUID and then run a `journalctl -M $UUID` on the container uuid to see logs.

```
~# machinectl -l
MACHINE                                  CLASS     SERVICE OS VERSION ADDRESSES
rkt-6d427a1c-6961-45a2-a055-721edddb8558 container rkt     -  -       -



~# journalctl -M rkt-6d427a1c-6961-45a2-a055-721edddb8558
```

If your systemd service starting your docker container is not listed under machinectl list, then add the following to your systemd service file that is starting your container:

```
[Service]
Slice=machine.slice
```

Cheers!